# How to keep third party 'Keys' secure in Android app

Tags: android, security, key

The next Android app I am creating uses third party APIs for: 1. Google API for geolocation. 2. Google APIs for Translation and 3. Zopim APIs for support chat. 
Now almost all such service providers uses 'KEY' to uniquely identify who is requesting data. To implement these services I need to use the unique KEY they give me while I sign up.

Now the KEY is nothing but a `String`. What concerns me is, it is very easy to decompile APKs to source code. In that case, is it possible that somebody can use my app's APK to read the KEY and misuse it?

If yes, what is the solution to it? There are many apps out there that uses such KEYS from service providers. What do they do?

Comment: There is no 100% solution. An attacker can always simulate what the device does to get to the key. You can only make it a bit harder for example by obfuscating the key.

Comment: @Henry Obfuscating? but how?

Comment: For example by XORing it with some pattern.

Comment: @Henry I am not saving it in a file or `sharedPreferences`, it is out there, open, in `string.xml` file. XORing wont help there I guess. Let me know if im wrong. Aint an expert. :)

Comment: You could put `key XOR pattern` in the strings.xml and keep `pattern` somewhere as constant in your program. The naive approach to just get the key from the strings file will then no longer work.

Comment: @Henry What that be easy for attackers to spot?

Comment: It's not too hard, but it requires at least some reverse engineering.

Answer (score 1):

You can save those keys encrypted in your app server and send them securely via SSL on log in

Comment: This just gives a false sense of security. An attacker can still simulate a device and so get to the key.